# segue to next ViewController and pass data if condition is valid

Tags: swift, if-statement, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to segue from first viewcontroller to the second one and pass the value of `var dateAndTime = NSDate()` to the second view controller.

My first approach was to segue from the first viewcontroller itself to the second one, define the name of the segue in Attributes inspector. 
Next, I link a button `@IBAction func nextButtonToFifthViewController` in the first viewcontroller, use an `if else` statement and `prepareForSegue`, but the code does not compile because I am not allowed to override `prepareForSegue`.

```
@IBAction func nextButtonToFifthViewController(sender: AnyObject) {
    if timeRestricted.contains(hourComponents){
        self.label.text = "Please choose a time betwen 7:00 - 19:00"
    } else {

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var destViewController:FifthViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! FifthViewController
        destViewController.dateAndTimeSelected = dateAndTime    }
       }
```

My second approach was to use `performSegueWithIdentifier`, but I wont be able to pass data to the next view controller because `dateAndTimeSelected` is not available for use in first view controller.

```
@IBAction func nextButtonToFifthViewController(sender: AnyObject) {
    if timeRestricted.contains(hourComponents){
        self.label.text = "Please choose a time betwen 7:00 - 19:00"
    } else {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("toFifthViewController", sender: self)
  dateAndTimeSelected = dateAndTime
}
```

Comment: in the first block of code, it seems that you're declaring `prepareForSegue` inside the ibaction func. You can't do that, you should close the ibaction and override the prepareForSegue outside of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `performSegueWithIdentifier` and `prepareForSegue` methods should be used together. First you call `performSegueWithIdentifier` when you already sure that you need move to new view controller, then you may configure your new view controller in `prepareForSegue`

```
@IBAction func nextButtonToFifthViewController(sender: AnyObject) {
    if timeRestricted.contains(hourComponents){
        self.label.text = "Please choose a time betwen 7:00 - 19:00"
    } else {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("toFifthViewController", sender: self)
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toFifthViewController" { 
        if let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? FifthViewController {
            destViewController.dateAndTimeSelected = dateAndTime
        }  
    }
}
```